# Acceleo: ecore to Python generator not working

Tags: python, generator, acceleo, ecore

I started to work with Acceleo for some weeks ago. I have a problem, when I try to start the example ecore-to-python-generator described here: (http://www.acceleo.org/pages/ecore-to-python-generator/en).
Because this generator isn't available in the new version of Acceleo, I downloaded a complete Eclipse package with Acceleo 2.7 from here (http://www.acceleo.org/pages/download-acceleo).

I did everything that is on the website. After choosing "Ecore to Python" module, it asks for Ecore Model. For this I select "org.acceleo.module.pim.ecore.gen.python". But if I start the generation process (by right-clicking on the default.chain file and Launch), there is the problem:

> [Resource '/org.acceleo.module.pim.ecore.gen.python/default' does not exist.]

Can you tell me, how to make a simple Python code generation?